# Google Authentication in Ionic Firebase app

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-oauth, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am developing an ionic application with firebase integration.For google authentication signInWithPopup,I do as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).It works in browser but the app crashes in Android 4.2 and in Android 5 gives the error message 'disallowed_useragent' with redirect to [this](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) link.

The libraries mentioned in the link are for native android apps.How can I accomplish that in ionic?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Google not is longer allow any more OAuth requests on your platform in embedded browsers known as “web-views”.

Here you can read the full communication talking about that: https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

Comment: I mentioned this link in my question.The libraries mentioned in the link are for native android apps.How can I accomplish that in ionic?